# How to solve the anti derivative of $\int \frac{1}{x^{2}-3x} dx$

Tags: integration

$\int \frac{1}{x^{2}-3x} dx$

I'm having trouble with understanding how to solve this, is there a reason why it's not the natural log of the denominator?

Comment: Differentiate the log of the denominator. Do you get the original integrand?

Comment: Hmm i suppose not, so then how should i go about solving this?

Comment: Complete the square, then partial fractions?

Comment: @kcris, partial fractions, sure, but no need to complete any squares, just factor the denominator.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in the answer - that was just my first gut response :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{x(x-3)}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{x-(x-3)}{x(x-3)}=\frac{1}{3}\left[\frac{1}{x-3}-\frac{1}{x}\right]$$